# angularjs share custom directive between two templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom directive with next params

```
 return {
        scope: {
            ngModel: '='
        },
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
    // directive code ...
}
```

and two templates which are using this directive

```
//template 1
  <div class="panel-body">
       <div ng-include src="'email.html'"></div>
  </div>

// email.html 
  <div id="template"
       ng-model="emailNotification"
       custom-directive></div>

// template 2
  <div class="panel-body">
       <div ng-include src="'sms.html'"></div>
  </div>

// sms.html 
  <div id="template"
       ng-model="smsNotification"
       custom-directive></div>
```

The problem here when I toggle between these two templates, ng-model inside 'custom-directive' doesn't refresh and value shares between two different ng-models. However I would like that directive wouldn't do that.

Where is my mistake and why does directive share this variable?

Comment: What do you mean by `toggle between these two templates`? Can you please set up a working fiddle to illustrate the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the = operator the directive's scope property binds to the parent's scope property by the same name. Since you are using ng-model on both instances of the directive inside the same parent, they both end up referencing the same ng-model.

If you want the evaluated value of the property from the parent scope, use @ binding.

```
return {
        scope: {
            ngModel: '@'
        },
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
    // directive code ...
}
```

Comment: So simple, this solved my problem! Thank you a lot, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

There are several different forms of scope for directives. You can use them all depending on the outcome you are expecting. They are `scope: true`, `scope: {}`, `scope: false`.

Each scope acts differently. The scope you are looking for is `scope: {}`, or `scope: true`.

If you do use `scope: {}` you want to ensure that the elements within are using the proper syntax `=`, `@` and `&`. In your case you will want to use the `@` symbol.

Explanation of symbols: [Explanation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjlxrDa8crVAhVG2GMKHbW-CkgQFggpMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmerrickchristensen.com%2Farticles%2Fangular-cheat-sheet.html&usg=AFQjCNEK7ekZ2TjZxELns5w9BEzof_20pA)

`@`: Pass this attribute as a string
`=`: Data bind this property to the directive's parent scope.
`&`: Pass in a function from the parent scope to be called later. Used to pass around lazily evaluated angular expressions.